# Custom/Modified Plugin - Run Batch File After Export

Tags: python, export, external-applications

I am looking for a way to easily start a batch/.bat file after the export via a plugin or an edited version of the FBX exporter. I need this to save me as much time as possible.

I have already tried to edit the python files of the FBX exporter accordingly, but no matter what I do, the .bat file is never started unfortunately.

So my question would be if this is possible at all and if there might be other methods or already existing plugins that can automatically start .bat files? And also, how can I set it up so that the batch file gets the export file path information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using a Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) `call` something like

```py
subprocess.call([PATH_TO_SCRIPT, SCRIPT_ARG, ...'])
```

You would have to find the right place in the exporter script to place the call, or write a wrapper script that first called the exporter and then invoked the subprocess.